# Different WAN IP address in router versus what is shown on IP checking websites

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I am trying to set up dyndns on my router—a [TP-Link WR1043ND V2](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR1043ND)—with latest DD-WRT firmware but the problem is that when I look at the router GUI it shows one WAN address and when I look at dyn.com it shows another address.

What should I do because I can’t get DDNS working, could this maybe be a double NATproblem or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

It very well could be a double NAT issue. I have seen ISP’s provide a private IP from their modem as it also acts as the router. Could this be the case with you?

The WAN IP that you see on your router what is the first octet of the IP?
if it starts with

```
192.168.x.x  
172.16.x.x -172.32.x.x   
10.x.x.x
```

These are non-routable private IP address and will have to be NAT’ed. More information can help diagnose this issue.

Comment: Hello. Yes my router ip that my router tells me shuld be my wan ip is 100.81.xx.xx and the ip that website [link]http://myip.dk/[link] gives me is 185.37.xx.xx

Comment: @Thomasstuck Are you sure that is 100.81.xx.xx? That's a public, routable IP address. Isn't it, instead, 10.81.xx.xx?

Answer (score 0):

Another issue could be about your connection getting proxied through another system. As an example, my employer is province wide, and we proxy all our Internet through our own IP address, but they leave to the Internet in another city. Every site I go to assumes I'm in another city, as long as I'm connected to this network.

Comment: ok if that is the case then ddns will not work or,  I could go with the easy version just buying a static ip from my isp but I would like to solve this problem. My main goal in this is to get ddns working.

Comment: Since you have both ip addresses, set up a small web server, and see which ip works from a friend's house

Answer (score 0):

Though everyone that preceded me has said something correct, I feel the answer to your query needs to be elucidated further.

The important IP address is the one reported by dyn.com, because this is the address that is recognized by anyone who is **not** a customer of your ISP. The other IP address, that on the WAN side of your router, is an internal IP (the correct expression is *private, non-routable*) address that can be used only within your ISP.

ISPs love to route their customers' surfing through their own machines, for a variety of reasons (see [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/679641/why-do-i-go-through-comcast-so-many-times-before-i-reach-a-website/679738#679738) for further details), mostly to cut on their own bills. So most of us have a WAN-side router address which is not *public, routable*. Basically, the address reported by your GUI is useless to you.

Whether you can reach your own home from outside your ISP depends not on your having a static IP (though that would definitely solve your problem)  but on your ISP allowing port-forwarding. This can be done even when you do not have a static IP, in part thanks to dyn.com. So, before encurring the further expense necessary to obtain a static IP, you should inquire whether port-forwarding is included in your subscription.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I am looking fore, yes I think i get the public non routable ip adress, I will try to call my isp and see if they have portforwording or not.

Comment: Update: I just called my isp and they says that it's not posible with my fiber subscription, am I maby saying somsing wreong till them or is just that way my isp deals with thinks.

Comment: I have found the reason why it's not working, my isp says that it's beacuse they are running NAT 44 and I then have to buy a static ip, is ther any way around this or is the only solution static ip form the isp.

Comment: @Thomasstuck If they do not allow port forwarding, getting a static IP is the only solution. Allowing or not port forwarding on NATted IPs is a commercial choice, not a technical one. The only alternative you may have is to buy a cheap Virtual Machine from another ISP, setup a reverse tunnel from home to the VM, and access home from there. It is a tad cheaper, but quite some work.

Comment: Great thx, I will just have to live with this not working or buy a static ip.